# Add class to build path using Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, buildpath

I'm using Anypoint Studio with Mule Server 3.5.0 CE.

I have a custom transformer named `CustomAsyncTransformer` which is defined in the class `AsyncTransformer`.

Within one of my Mule flows:

```xml
<custom-transformer name="CustomAsyncTransformer" class="ca.mpac.esb.component.webservice.AsyncTransformer">
</custom-transformer>
```

This causes the following message to be displayed:

```
Unable to find type 'ca.mpac.esb.component.webservice.AsyncTransformer' on build path of project TEST-PROJECT
```

However, `AsyncTransformer.class` has been added to the build path; it is located in `src/main/app` which is designated as a source folder. I've also tried adding it directly to the build path, creating a new source folder, and adding it to other source folders. Still no change.

What am I doing wrong? How can I add this class to the build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java source code should be in `src/main/java`. So your approach to add add a new source folder is correct, just use `src/main/java` so your Maven build will pick it up too.

Studio should pick the class from it. If it's not the case, it's maybe a bug? Or maybe something else: to find out show a screenshot of your application directory layout.